# Keras Regression Model Not outputting correctly

Tags: python, keras

I have put together a `keras` regression model to predict california housing prices using housing data and its not outputting correctly.

Can see full code on [google colabs][1]:

I think I have scaled it right and put in the right variables but I was using code from  a classification problem to model off so it might not be correct.

```
    sc = StandardScaler()

    X = sc.fit_transform(hous.drop('median_house_value', axis=1))
    y = hous['median_house_value'].values



    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,
                                                    random_state=22,
                                                    test_size=0.2)
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(32, input_shape=(6,), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
    model.compile(Adam(lr=0.05),
              loss='mean_squared_error',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, verbose=2,
              validation_split=0.4)


    y_pred = np.log(X_test)

    y_test_class = np.log(y_test, axis=1)
    y_pred_class = np.log(y_pred, axis=1)
```

The result is:

```
Epoch 50/50
 - 1s - loss: 5401748800.5233 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 5651061434.0796 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
/Users/Avi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:18: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-4f45ffa7384b> in <module>
     18 y_pred = np.log(X_test)
     19 
---> 20 y_test_class = np.log(y_test, axis=1)
     21 y_pred_class = np.log(y_pred, axis=1)
     22 

TypeError: 'axis' is an invalid keyword to ufunc 'log'"


  [1]: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dcUuTVVDGwxHn2O5qqJk0wgiEf83MslN/view?usp=sharing
```

Comment: The log function of numpy does provide a keyword axis. What are you even trying to do?

Comment: @LongNguyen I am trying to run an ANN linear regression for predicting california real estate prices..